# Relation between setwise and weak convergence of measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a metric space. We say that a sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of finite measures on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ converges weakly to a finite measure $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ if $$\int f\:{\rm d}\mu_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int f\:{\rm d}\mu\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in C_b(E).$$ Now consider the condition of setwise convergence: $$\mu_n(B)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mu(B)\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal B(E)\tag2.$$

> Which relation holds between $(1)$ and $(2)$? Does one imply the other?

For example, $(2)$ clearly implies $(1)$ for all $\mathcal E$-measurable $f$ with $|f(E)|\in\mathbb N$. But can we say more?

Comment: https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/weak-convergence-and-the-portmanteau-lemma/

Comment: @d.k.o. So, since $(2)$ in my question does clearly imply (e) in the Portmanteau Lemma, we should be able to conclude $(1)$ from $(2)$, right? The restriction to probability measures shouldn't be a restriction, since we can simply normalize $\mu_n,\mu$ here. Do we need to assume that the measures are "Borel" (in whatever sense the term is used there)?

Comment: A Borel measure is any measure on $\mathcal{B}(E)$. Also (2) implies (1) but not vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that $(2)\implies(1)$, even without using the portmanteau theorem; let $f$ be any bounded measurable function; then for $\varepsilon>0$ we can approximate $f$ uniformly (in a tolerance of $\varepsilon$) by a simple function $\phi=\sum_{j=1}^N\lambda_i\chi_{E_i}$, where $E_i$ are pairwise disjoint Borel sets. Then by triangle inequality
$$|\int fd\mu_n-\int fd\mu|\le2\varepsilon+|\int\phi d\mu_n-\int\phi d\mu|\le2\varepsilon+\sum_{j=1}^N|\lambda_j|\cdot|\mu_n(E_j)-\mu(E_j)|$$
so for large $n$ we have $|\int fd\mu_n-\int fd\mu|<3\varepsilon$, i.e. that $\int fd\mu_n\to\int fd\mu$; this is true for all bounded measurable functions, not just continuous bounded ones. So you can see that $(2)$ is much stronger than $(1)$.